# What is the best way to use PreparedStatement when I have to insert 100s of very similar rows?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have to `**inserts 100s of rows**` into the database such as all the column values are exactly same except one. For example sake consider a table

```
------------------
|UserId|Timestamp|
------------------
```

Now `**only timestamp is changing for every insert**`.

Is it advisable to use prepared statement in the following way ?

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Pings (UserId,Timestamp) VALUES (?,?)"; 

pstmt.setInt(1,001); //setting user is 
while(true){
   pstmt.setTimestamp(2,getTimestamp());
   pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
}
```

Compared to

```
while(true){
   pstmt.setInt(1,001);
   pstmt.setTimestamp(2,getTimestamp());
   pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
}
```

Will first approach work given that I am setting 1st column value only once ?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use batching with [`PreparedStatement.addBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) and [`Statement.executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29). That might look something like,

```
int count = 0;
while (true) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, 001);
    pstmt.setTimestamp(2, getTimestamp());
    pstmt.addBatch();
    if (++count % 50 == 0) { // <-- batch size of 50.
        pstmt.executeBatch();
    }
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Thanks but also tell me if pstmt.setInt(1,001); can be outside the loop. Does it really need to be set every time ?

Comment: @AksharPrabhuDesai Best practice would be to set it every time, performance wise I doubt it will make any measurable difference. Also, why did you put leading `0`(s) in `setInt(int, int)`? That's `setInt(1,1);`